# Checked radio input if there is value

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to show radio as checked if the array `$row['featured'];` = 1 if `$row['featured']; = 0` don't show as checked

here is the code

```
    <?php   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
    <td width="6%" align="center"><input type="radio" name="features" value="<?php echo $row['featured']; ?>" /></td>
    <td width="35%"><?php echo $row['job_title']; ?></td>
    <td width="24%"><?php echo $row['category_name'] ?></td>
    <td width="15%"><?php echo $row['job_location']; ?></td>
    <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['status'] ?></td>
    <td width="10%"><a href="job_edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['job_id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="features" value="<?php echo $row['featured']; ?>" 
    <?php echo ($row['featured'] == 1?'checked':'')?>/>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/azfGKm0F)

Comment: checked is not an XHTML standard, which you are using since you used /> for closing tag! it should had been checked="checked" ;)

Comment: @linuxeasy the OP did not state it needed to be XHTML compliant, and if it needed to be, the code is self explanatory to change

Comment: I was trying to use switch.
WHen I get this solution I'm so happy

Comment: I was trying to use switch. When I get this solution I'm so happy.
the reason why code is so small and simple

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" name="features" value="<?php echo $row['featured']; ?>"
<?php echo $row['featured']?'checked="checked"':'';?>/>
```

Comment: are you sure that featured value is either 1 or 0 only?

Comment: I was trying to use switch. When I get this solution I'm so happy.
the reason why code is so small and simple
thanks for ur help